# ruby on rails :-page automatically getting redirected

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following controller
I call the index action from jquery AJAX and it does get called but instead of displaying the contents of the page it gets automatically redirected
Note- i dont use show feeds defined in the following controller

```
class AdAssistedController < CommonController

  def initialize

        super
        @pageJs = ['ad_assisted']
        @pageCSS = ['ad_creator', 'fbx_launcher', 'score_dashboard', 
                    'slider_dashboard_new', 'score-dashboard_new',
                    'jquery-ui']
  end

  def index

    begin
      @feed_names = FbxLauncher::Feed.find(:all)
    rescue Exception => e
      log_error(e.message)
      log_error(e.backtrace)
    end

  end

  def show_feeds

    begin
      @feed_names = FbxLauncher::Feed.find(:all)
      rescue Exception => e
        log_error(e.message)
        log_error(e.backtrace)
      end
    respond_to do |format|
        format.js { render :partial => 'show_feeds'}
        format.html { render :partial => 'show_feeds'}
    end
  end
end
```

following is my index page

```
<div id="show_feeds">
<select id="rss_names">     
    <% @feed_names.each do |feed| %>
            <% @feed1= "#{feed.name}" %>
    <option>    <%="#{@emp1}" %> </option> 
    <% end %>
</select>
```

following is my jquery call

```
jQ("#ad_factory_assisted_ads").click(function() {
call_with_ajax("#hide","/ad_assisted/index", {})
```

});

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
call_with_ajax("#hide","/ad_assisted/index", {})
```

Try

```
call_with_ajax("#hide","/ad_assisted/", {})
```

run `rake routes` if you want to see all the valid routes